# django <model>.objects manager shows undefined variable from export in pydev + eclipse

Tags: django, django-models, pydev

In a django model the objects manager is auto created. However you can also manually specify an objects manager.

It appears that adding a objects manager to the model class confuses pydev and all class methods on the manager appear as undefined variables from import

```
Model.objects.all()
```

However it works for inherited model managers

Code example (the `all()` is underlined).

manager_test_def.py:

```py
from django.db import models


class MyManager(models.Manager):
    pass


class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass


class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager.from_query_set(CustomQuerySet)()
```

manager_test_use.py:

```py
from cluster_manager.manager_test_def import MyModel


def f():
    MyModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: Please post the actual code and example on how to reproduce the issue to the PyDev tracker: https://brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev

Comment: Added code to reproduce.